# Backup and restore Azure Storage Emulator data

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there any information out there on how to backup and restore the data in the Azure Storage Emulator? (Notice this is not the live version of Azure.)

We are developing several different solutions against Windows Azure Storage but since the storage emulator is basically just "one storage account" we need to separate the data per project. Are there easy/handy ways to do this without having to manually extract & put back all the data?

Answer (score 0):

Storage emulator data is stored in a local database.  I'd assume that could be backed up and restored as needed. But, never tried personally.